# How do I add parameters to programs launched from Lubuntu's Application Launch Bar?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, lxterminal

I've just started trying out *Lubuntu 12.04*. I know I can edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to assign keyboard shortcuts to open programs with certain  parameters. For example, I can specify that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens *lxterminal* with a certain size like this:

```
<!-- Launch a terminal on Ctrl + Alt + T-->
<keybind key="C-A-T">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxterminal --geometry=148x30</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

But how do I do the same thing for *lxterminal* when started by clicking on its icon in my *Application Launch Bar*? In other words, I'd like to have the same-sized terminal window if I click on the *lxterminal* icon in the Application Launch Bar or if I start *lxterminal* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Is it possible? How do I do that?
As far as I could make out, editing `~/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf` by adding `geometry=148x30` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the modification made to `lubuntu-rc.xml`, you will need to edit your terminal desktop file:

```
gksudo leafpad /usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop
```

Look for the `Exec=` line and replace with `Exec=lxterminal --geometry=148x30`.

It appears that logging out and in is needed to make this change take effect. (To give effect to changes in `lubuntu-rc.xml`, one just needs to run openbox --reconfigure from a terminal.)
Now, the terminal will have the same geometry, whether invoked by the keyboard or via the Application Launchbar.

Comment: looks great! glad it worked....